# Tomar datos de un string CSV String C#

Tags: c#, string, csv, data

Tengo una pequeña aplicacion en C# para escritorio donde tengo un método que hace una petición get que en respuesta recibe un string con el contenido de un fichero csv, cuando ya lo tengo catcheado le quito los espacios en blanco con el metodo trim y pues me quedo con una cadena con todos los campos y valores separados por comas (,).

Despues de esto he colocado cada campo del string en una posicion de un arreglo string de esta forma:

```
string[] arrayContent;
arrayContent = respCont.Split(',', ' ');
```

donde respCont es la respuesta del servidor luego de que se la han quitado los espacios con trim().

Ahora me he quedado con un arreglo en el que no he podido relacionar los campos, en una de las lineas del fichero el coloca los encabezados de cada dato que mostrara luego, seria algo como esto:

```
Date-and-time,"Encabezado-Dato1","Encabezado-Dato2","Encabezado-Dato3",
2018-08-22 14:10:00,valordato1,valordato2,valordato3,
2018-08-22 14:10:00,valordato1,valordato2,valordato3,
2018-08-22 14:10:00,valordato1,valordato2,valordato3,
2018-08-22 14:10:00,valordato1,valordato2,valordato3,
2018-08-22 14:10:00,valordato1,valordato2,valordato3,
```

La idea es que yo pudiese relacionar los valores de Encabezado-Dato1 con los valores correspondientes de ValorDato1, pero creo que de esta forma no es posible, existe alguna forma de que pueda gestionar mejor esta csv y poder acceder a estos datos de esta forma en C#.

Comment: Esto te puede ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable

Comment: Mmmm esta interesante aunque según vi trabaja sobre el fichero propiamente, si hay alguna opción para que trabaje sobre la cadena pues seria muy útil. muchas gracias.

Comment: El csv es siempre el mismo?

Comment: La estructura es la misma pero pueden haber campos vacíos de la forma; 2018-08-22 14:10:00,valordato1,valordato2,valordato3,,,,,,,,,valordatoN,,,valorDaton+1

Comment: @DVertel ¿el ejemplo en la pregunta es correcto? porque el ejemplo no muestra si la respuesta del get tiene saltos de línea `\r\n` . Con esos saltos se puede determinar las filas que tiene la respuesta y se establece que la primera fila son los nombres de las columnas.

Comment: Como dice @MauricioAriasOlave, lo normal en los archivos csv es que cada fila tenga un separador, normalmente un retorno de carro. Si esto es así, no entiendo exactamente cual es el problema, haces split primero por el salto de linea y posteriormente por `,`